# The head pointer won't stay in the front (C++)

Tags: c++, linked-list

I'm trying to create a linked list, I have a Node class and a List class.  The list constructor sets Head and Tail (of type Node*) to nullptr.  Both classes are templatized.  My insert method for the list won't keep the head pointer pointed at the beginning and I'm really not sure why.  It's only assigned once when head == nullptr.

Here is the insert method.

```
void insert(T item)
    {
      //insert item at end
      //allocate new node
      Node<T> tempNode = Node<T>(item);
      Node<T> *temp = &tempNode;
      //put in data
      temp->setData(item);
      //end of list set to null
      temp->setNext(nullptr); 

      //if first node
      if (head == nullptr)
      {
        //head and tail are set to temp
        head = temp;
        cout << "head1: " << head->getData() << endl;
        tail = temp;
      } else //not first node in list
      { cout << "head: " << head->getData() << endl;
        tail->setNext(temp);
        tail = temp;
      }

      cout << "tail: " << tail->getData() << endl;
      cout << "head: " << head->getData() << endl;
      cout << "head: " << head << endl;
    }
```

the cout is just for me to see what's going on.  Every `head->getData()` Produces the value currently held in temp however when I print head it is the same address every time.

just to be clear I have a separate test file that loops 0-9 attempting insert with each value.  The results of that are...

```
head1: 0
tail: 0
head: 0
head: 0x7fffc574dc40
head: 1
tail: 1
head: 1
head: 0x7fffc574dc40
head: 2
tail: 2
head: 2
head: 0x7fffc574dc40
head: 3
tail: 3
head: 3
head: 0x7fffc574dc40
head: 4
tail: 4
head: 4
head: 0x7fffc574dc40
head: 5
tail: 5
head: 5
head: 0x7fffc574dc40
head: 6
tail: 6
head: 6
head: 0x7fffc574dc40
head: 7
tail: 7
head: 7
head: 0x7fffc574dc40
head: 8
tail: 8
head: 8
head: 0x7fffc574dc40
head: 9
tail: 9
head: 9
head: 0x7fffc574dc40
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One major problem are these two lines:

```
Node<T> tempNode = Node<T>(item);
Node<T> *temp = &tempNode;
```

Here you make `temp` point to the *local* variable `tempNode`. When the function `insert` returns the life-time of `tempNode` ends and it is destructed. The pointer `temp` (and all copies of that pointer) will become invalid. Attempting to use this pointer afterward will lead to *undefined behavior*.

The usual solution to create new nodes is to allocate them dynamically:

```
Node<T>* temp = new Node<T>(item);
```

You of course have to remember to `delete` all the nodes you create this way, to avoid *memory leaks*.

Comment: THANK YOU! That fixed it.  I tried using the new operator before but I wasn't adding (item) to the end as I wasn't aware I could do that... Thank you so much!!

Comment: Your C++ book should have a section on creating (and constructing) objects